# Segmentation fault on recv() of socket.h

Tags: c, sockets, udp, segmentation-fault, recv

I got a strange segmentation fault when executing recv() function of . Here's the function used recv() in my code.

```
void* recv_and_update(void* t) 
{
    int tid = (int) t;
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int numbytes;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    int flag = 1, len = sizeof(int);

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to create socket on thread %d.\n", tid);
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons( node.port );
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );

    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, len);

    printf("start binding.\n");

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)))
    {
        printf("Failed to bind socket on thread %d.\n", tid);
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("binding finished.\n");

    while (1) 
    {
        printf("start recv()\n");

        if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0)) < 0)
        {
            printf("Failed to receive msgs on thread %d.\n",
                    tid);
            exit(-1);
        }

        printf("end recv(), numbytes=%d\n", numbytes);
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        translate_and_update(buf);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The most weird part of this problem is that the segmentation fault doesn't happen every time. Usually after 100 or 200 times of receiving ( or less times occasionally ). And when it happens, the program would only output my "start recv()" sentence without "end recv()".

So I think the problem happens right in the recv() function, but I failed to figure out why and how to fix this.

Comment: It can also crash in another thread while `recv()` is waiting for data. But this is just another guess. If you want to know exactly run it under a debugger.

Comment: Every time this fault happens, it outputs a `start recv()` without `end recv()`. It should not be like this if the error happens in another thread. (Oh, I forgot to mention that this thread is the only receiving thread in my program.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your discription it looks like `recv()` is blocking and the app crashes due to an error at a different location, will say in a different thread.

Nevertheless `buf` is declared one byte too small.

If having read `BUFLEN` bytes `numbytes` will be `BUFLEN` and the following call will write to memory *not* being allocated to be `buf`:

```
buf[numbytes] = '\0';
```

To fix this change

```
char buf[BUFLEN];
```

to be

```
char buf[BUFLEN + 1];
```

Comment: I've tried to write `recv(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN - 1, 0)` which may does the same effect of your modification. However, this didn't work, either.

Comment: lastland: Then there has to be *another* error! You might like to show us what `translate_and_update()` does

Comment: Since every time this error happens, the output is `start recv()` without `end recv()`, I think the error happens exactly in the recv() function part, if I didn't miss or misunderstand something.

Comment: @lastland: Ok, from this fact I'd draw the conclusion `recv()` is blocking and the app crashes due to an error at a different location, will say in a differnt thread.

Comment: Oh, you could be right and I could really miss something stupid. Now I'm trying to follow this lead and figure out what exactly happens. Thank you.

Comment: Problem resovled. Thank you. I can accept your answer if you are willing to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

The SIGSEGV could happen elsewhere, e.g. in `translate_and_update`.

Why don't you enable core dumps (with e.g. [`ulimit -c` bash builtin](http://www.basiclinuxcommand.com/linux-command/ulimit.html)) and debug the post-mortem core with `gdb yourprog core` ?